# Imgur sideloading using api is giving me 302

Tags: javascript, api, imgur

I am trying to use sideloading with imgur's api.

```
$.get("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?", {
    url: www.example.com/blah.jpg
},function(response){
        var url = response.upload.links.original;
        var thumb_url = response.upload.links.small_square;
        uploadSuccess(response,url,thumb_url);
});
```

However, I am getting a 302 found:

`http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json?&url=http://www.example.com/blah.jpg`

and then it redirects to:

`http://imgur.com/upload?url=http://www.example.com/blah.jpg`

which then just loads forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the 'url' parameter to 'image' and that seemed to solve this issue.

Comment: awesome it worked! to @deltree, just change it so it says image: www.example.com/blah.jpg. Also, you need to provide the api key as well